# LinQ query unsupported LinQ queries and two-stage queries

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to get distinct value of moduleName from Assessment table. ModuleName is lookup column in Assessment-List. ModuleName is linked from ModuleList. Please tell me how would I get distinct count of module name from Assessment List?

```
protected void drpCoursesName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SiteEntitiesDataContext siteEntitiesDataContext = new SiteEntitiesDataContext(SPContext.Current.Site.Url))
    {
        EntityList<AssessmentItem> listItems = siteEntitiesDataContext.GetList<AssessmentItem>("Assessment");
        var distinctModuleCount = from module1 in listItems
                                  group module1 by new { module1.ModuleName }
                                  into grp
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      count1=grp.Count(),
                                  };
        int modulecount=distinctModuleCount.Count();

        foreach(var item in distinctModuleCount)
        {
            Label lbl1 = new Label();
            lbl1.Text = modulecount.ToString();
            PlaceHolderAssessment.Controls.Add(lbl1);
        }//end of for loop
    }//end of Data Context
}//end of method
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was a little difficult to interpret exactly what you are after, but I hope the following helps.

Given a class defined as:

```
public class AssessmentItem
{
    public string ModuleName { get; set; }
}
```

And the following code that initializes and queries a collection of these classes:

```
var items = new List<AssessmentItem>
    {
        new AssessmentItem { ModuleName = "Test 1" },
        new AssessmentItem { ModuleName = "Test 1" },
        new AssessmentItem { ModuleName = "Test 2" },
        new AssessmentItem { ModuleName = "Test 2" },
        new AssessmentItem { ModuleName = "Test 2" }
    };

var grouped = items.GroupBy(x => x.ModuleName);
Debug.WriteLine("Distinct modules {0}", grouped.Count());
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} has {1} entries", group.Key, group.Count());
}
```

You will receive the following output:

```
Distinct modules 2
Test 1 has 2 entries
Test 2 has 3 entries
```